# SBT - regression in 0.13.9?

Tags: sbt, ivy

Consider the following (minimal) build.sbt:

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ("org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.6.0" ),
      ("org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "1.1.0" ) 
    )
```

In 0.13.8 and below, this build works, by which I mean commands such as update and package complete successfully. In 0.13.9, these same commands fail with the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6

I can work around this by explicitly excluding commons-codec, but I'm curious as to what is causing this to fail in the newer version of SBT. The error message isn't very informative; is this an issue in SBT or the version of Ivy that 0.13.9 is using, or should the build have failed in earlier versions of SBT as well?

Answer (score 0):

(the following is just based on some googling and some trial and error, not on real expertise. why it doesn't just evict the older versions, I have no idea)

Add this to your build.sbt:

```
dependencyOverrides += "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.6"

dependencyOverrides += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "16.0.1"
```

and the problem will go away. Based on Eugene's advice at https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/654#issuecomment-64241673.

If you want details on what is requiring what, typing `last *:update` after `update` finishes will show a trace.